# Cannot start jupyter in conda environment using keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, anaconda

I want to open Jupyter activating tensorflow env from conda. All of the commands below, work fine from the terminal, but not when I write them in the 'command' tab when setting a keyboard shortcut in Gnome.

1. `source activate tensorflow; jupyter notebook;`
2. `source activate tensorflow || jupyter notebook`
3. `source activate tensorflow && jupyter notebook`
4. Writing this in a .sh file and executing of keypress:

   ```
   source activate tensorflow
   jupyter notebook
   ```

Any idea why it is not working and how to make it work? 
I don't want to have 2 separate key shortcuts for each.